# Best way to model user resource for rest api

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am creating a REST service which provides standard operations like get user by id, add user, remove user, list users etc. I am using Google Cloud Endpoints for this project.

My current model uses a class called `User` derived from `DisplayableUser`. `User` contains sensitive info like passwords while `DisplayableUser` only contains fields safe to pass to client. Whenever I need to provide a JSON representation for user, I simply cast `User` to `DisplayableUser` which then gets serialized and passed to client.

My question is, is this the correct way to do this? The approach I tried unsuccessfully before this was :

Introduce a separate class called `Password`. This class contains a reference to the `User` (which now doesn't contain any sensitive data) and the actual hashed password. I am using objectify to interact with datastore BTW.

```
@Entity
public class Password
{
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Load
    Ref<User> user;
    String passwordHash;

    .....
}
```

The problem I am facing here once I retrieve the `User` from datastore, how do I retrieve the corresponding `Password` entity?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I never store the password in the database because of security concerns. I store only hashes. You cannot get what is not there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**
Instead of using a referenceProperty, why not make password a child of user? Like that, once you have your user, you can easily retrieve the password, with something like

> p= Password.query(Password.ancestorKey == user_ID).fetch()

This has the added bonus of forcing your query to be consistent.  The fact that the user will be locked when you query its password shouldn't be a problem (depending on your use cases of course).

**SOLUTION 2** Another solution would be to create password with only "hashed password" and "user_id" as parameters.

**SOLUTION 3** I personally would dump the displayable user and just use user.  When you query for "safe" info, just use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries) to see the fields you want and nothing more

Comment: Regarding the 1st solution, won't it be a performance problem to always retrieve all the passwords once you have the user?

Comment: @iTwenty, this was mostly to show you the idea of it. You can always do p= Password.query(Password.ancestorKey == user_ID).fetch() (edited in answer)

Comment: Ok. Still new to Datastore, so I am not quite sure of all the ways to query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @iTwenty yeah there are quite a couple ways to do the same things in the datastore. I would suggest playing with it a bit, checking your different methods and trying them out to get a feel of the differences :). Also if this answer actually helped you, feel free to accept it so whoever lands on your question has a better idea of which one to look at ^^

Comment: @iTwenty thank you :) enjoy playing in the app engine world ;) you'll see, it's quite a bit different then what you might be used to (relational databases and whatnot), but the datastore actually offers a LOT of power, once you design with its limitations in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a mismatch between your data model and your data transfer (or display) model, it's time to create separate classes. Sharing your data model classes client-side can be convenient for simple cases, but as soon as you start going through contortions to get the right data, it's easier to just make DTOs. Use projectlombok.org to get rid of the boilerplate and DTOs become super lightweight.

Comment: I do have separate classes right now. The client displayable User class acts as parent class of User class with password. Do you mean remove the inheritance and have two totally separate classes?

Comment: Yes, inheritance structures like this qualify as the kind of contortion that makes me think creating a 100% separate DTO will help. The other contortion that looks very odd to me is having the Password as a separate entity. But ultimately this is your codebase, do what you think looks 'right' to you.